# If-else usage in Lazarus

Tags: delphi, pascal, lazarus

I'm new to Lazarus and today I faced an issue with if-else usage. Everything is ok while there is only an if statement but when I'm trying to write an if-else statement this error shows up:

`unit1.pas(48, 3) Fatal: Syntax error, ";" expected but "Else" found`

I'm not sure if I need to wrap code inside the statements with `begin end`, but [this FreePascal wiki page](https://wiki.freepascal.org/IF) shows it like this

My code:

```pascal
unit Unit1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, StdCtrls, Math;

type

  { TForm1 }

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Edit3: TEdit;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private

  public

  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  a, b, c, d, x, x1, x2:real;
begin
  a := strToFloat(Edit1.Text);
  b := strToFloat(Edit2.Text);
  c := strToFloat(Edit3.Text);
  d := Power(b, 2) - 4 * a * c;
  if d > 0 then
    x1 := (-b + sqrt(d))/(2 * a);
    x2 := (-b - sqrt(d))/(2 * a);
    Label1.Caption := 'x1 = ' + floatToStr(x1) + #10 + 'x2 = ' + floaTToStr(x2)
  else
    if d < 0 then
      Label1.Caption := 'Розв*язків немає';
    else
      x1 := (-b + sqrt(d))/(2 * a);
      Label1.Caption := 'x = ' + floatToStr(x);
end.
```

Comment: If you look a the page you link to, you find this example: `if BooleanExpression then
  StatementIfTrue
else
  StatementIfFalse;` at the top. Immediately below this example, there is a note: "Note there is never a semicolon ; immediately before the else." Also, the compiler error is fairly clear, isn't it?

Comment: Pascal has never allowed a semicolon before an else, i.e. you need to remove it from: `Label1.Caption := 'Розв*язків немає';`

Comment: Also note, I thought that if there were more than 1 line in an ```if``` condition or the ```else``` condition, you need to enclose them between ```begin ... end```

Comment: Also, if you need more than a single statement to belong to a branch, you must use `begin..end` blocks. So in your code above, the `if d > 0 then` only applies to `x1 := (-b + sqrt(d))/(2 * a);` and not to the two next lines. You need to put these three lines within a `begin..end` block, so that this entire block will belong to the `if d > 0 then`. And, of course, no semicolon on this block's `end`, because there is an `else` after it!

Comment: @ewong: There can be any number of lines without any need for a `begin..end` block. But there can only be a single *statement*.

Comment: Perhaps the poster compares the indented statements in Python with pascal. From indentation it *looks* correct, but as others have pointed out, having multiple statements under the `if ... ` requires `if (this) then begin  {statements here ... }  end`

Comment: Indeed, in Delphi (and most other programming languages except Python), whitespace in general and indentation in particular is ignored (\*); the compiler doesn't care about the indentation. So as far as the compiler is concerned, the program is exactly the same if you remove the leading whitespace from every line. [\* Nitpick: Of course whitespace is used to delimit tokens and is very much preserved in string literals.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be trying to use indentation to group code under statements. Pascal doesn't use indentation for nesting code (I'm honestly unsure what its called). You need to use `begin` and then afterwards `end`.

Meaning you code should look as follows:

```pascal
  if d > 0 then
  begin
    // All 3 lines below will run if "d > 0"
    x1 := (-b + sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);
    x2 := (-b - sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);
    Label1.Caption := 'x1 = ' + floatToStr(x1) + #10 + 'x2 = ' + floatToStr(x2);
  end // Do not ";" since the if statement is not over yet
  else if d < 0 then
  begin
    Label1.Caption := 'Розв*язків немає';
  end // Do not ";" since the if statement is not over yet
  else
  begin
    x1 := (-b + sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);
    Label1.Caption := 'x = ' + floatToStr(x);
  end; // End of the if statment
```

Comment: imo, it would be better to not have a begin..end block for d < 0, to illustrate how code should look when it is not needed

Comment: I agree with you @RaelB . I did it like this because OP doesn't seem to be familiar with pascal at all so this would be simpler. Also I didn't know how to properly explain it in English so that it would make sense for beginners like OP